# inserting unique rows to sqlite3 with python

Tags: python, csv, sqlite

I am writing a python script that is converting a CSV file into an sqlite3 database. There is an id column that i have set up to be "primary key unique" and i know in the CSV file there is repeating information. How to i tell it to only store non-repeating information into the database?

Here is what i have so far.

```
for row in reader:
  counter += 1
  #this gets rid of the header in the CSV file
  if counter == 1:
    continue
  s = (row[0],row[2],row[1],row[4],row[3],row[7],row[8],row[9])
  course = row[5].split(" ") 
  c = (row[0],course[0],course[1],row[6])
  #when it hits here and sees that two ids are the same, it crashes because it will not allow non-unique values.
  curs.execute('''insert into students (id,lastname,firstname,major,email,city,state,zip)
    values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', s)
  curs.execute('''insert into classes (id,subjcode,coursenumber,termcode)
    values (?,?,?,?)''', c)
```

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [INSERT OR IGNORE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html):

```
curs.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO students (id,lastname,firstname,major,email,city,state,zip) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', s)
```

This will insert the first row with a duplicate `id`, but ignore all successive duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by using a `UNIQUE` constraint on your tables' id, and then use a `INSERT OR IGNORE`